# python3 How to read json file, modify and write?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read a json file, modify and then save the modified version.
Unfortunately, the content of the file, instead of being saved, adds another json to the end of the original one.

my code:

```
with open(os.environ.get("WORKSPACE")+"/test.json", 'r+') as test_file:
    test = json.load(test_file)
    test['COMPONENTS'] = "test components"
    json.dump(test, test_file)
```

test.json
`{"STAGE": "Test", "DATE": "2023-02-17", "TIME": "13:27", "COMPONENTS": ""}`

after running code
`{"STAGE": "Test", "DATE": "2023-02-17", "TIME": "13:27", "COMPONENTS": ""}{"STAGE": "Test", "DATE": "2023-02-17", "TIME": "13:27", "COMPONENTS": "test components"}`

expected result:
`{"STAGE": "Test", "DATE": "2023-02-17", "TIME": "13:27", "COMPONENTS": "test components"}`

Please point out what I am doing wrong

My environment
Python 3.10.9
macos 12.3.1

I try to use w+

```
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
StopIteration: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    test = json.load(test_file)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it, like UpmostScarab said, is to just open the file twice. If you only want to open it once for some reason, you can read, then `seek(0)`, then write, and finally `truncate`:

```
with open(os.environ.get("WORKSPACE")+"/test.json", 'r+') as test_file:
    test = json.load(test_file)
    test['COMPONENTS'] = "test components"
    test_file.seek(0)
    json.dump(test, test_file)
    test_file.truncate()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works great. I am learning python, didn't know seek() method.

Comment: If your question has been answered, can you mark an answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is adding a `+` to your opening modes. Also note that `w+` would truncate the file, so there will be no JSON to read. I think what you should do is:

```
with open(os.environ.get("WORKSPACE")+"/test.json", 'r') as test_file:
    test = json.load(test_file)
    test['COMPONENTS'] = "test components"

with open(os.environ.get("WORKSPACE")+"/test.json", 'w') as test_file:
    json.dump(test, test_file)
```

Comment: When you use the "with" statement for a file operation, termination automatically closes the file. Your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Pawel I'm not sure what the issue is, I close it and then reopen it. Have you tried to run it though? What error did you get? 
After you did json.load, there's no more operations on the file. And then you open it before json.dump

Comment: @Pawel this solution will work for what you want.

Comment: @UpmostScarab Sorry, I was wrong. It works as you wrote. I must have made a mistake while checking the file.